# How to setup tvheadend on raspbian so that I can record TV shows streamed by HDHomeRun?

Tags: raspbian

I want to use my Raspberry Pi to record TV shows as video files.

I have a [HDHomeRun](https://www.silicondust.com/hdhomerun/) device that can stream live TV to my Raspberry Pi via Ethernet. How can I set up the [tvheadend](https://tvheadend.org) PVR backend accordingly, which provides a web interface to set up video recordings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also the [HDHomeRun HOWTO guide from tvheadend.org](https://tvheadend.org/projects/tvheadend/wiki/HDHomerun).

## 1. Install the HDHomeRun Linux Drivers

First of all, you need drivers for communicating with your HDHomeRun.

Assuming your HDHomeRun device is connected to your network, access http://my.hdhomerun.com for installation instructions on Linux. This means installing `libhdhomerun` and the HDHomeRun Config GUI from source:

```
cd # assuming you do this in your home folder - but you could do it anywhere else
wget http://download.silicondust.com/hdhomerun/libhdhomerun_20150826.tgz
wget http://download.silicondust.com/hdhomerun/hdhomerun_config_gui_20150826.tgz
tar xvzf libhdhomerun_20150826.tgz 
tar xvzf hdhomerun_config_gui_20150826.tgz 
cd hdhomerun_config_gui/
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
./configure 
make
sudo make install
cd ..
# archives and source folders can be deleted once the driver is installed
rm -rf libhdhomerun* hdhomerun_config_gui*
```

## 2. Install the V4L/DVB kernel module

Next, you need your Linux kernel to be able to stream TV on your Raspberry Pi. There's a module for that, but it'll need to be compiled from source. Let's go!

### 2a. Upgrade to jessie

In case you're still using the raspbian wheezy distribution, you'll have to upgrade it to raspbian jessie first, in order to be able to install a recent version of the gcc compiler.

```
# Ensure wheezy is up-to-date
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
# Switch the apt repositories to jessie
sed -i 's/wheezy/jessie/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
# Install the jessie packages
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

### 2b. Download the kernel sources

You can use the [`rpi-source`](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki) script to install the kernel source for your raspbian image.

```
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source -O /usr/bin/rpi-source && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-source && /usr/bin/rpi-source -q --tag-update
rpi-source
```

The script performs a `gcc` version check, which might fail. In that case, follow the instructions to install the right version of `gcc` and try again.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 50
rpi-source
```

Once the linux kernel source is downloaded, build its scripts. If you don't, the next step will fail because it can't find `recordmcount`, which is one of those scripts.

```
cd linux
make scripts
cd ..
```

### 2c. Compile and install the V4L/DVB module

The [LinuxTV community](http://www.linuxtv.org)  develops and maintains the Linux Kernel Media Subsystems. See their wiki page [How to Obtain, Build and Install V4L/DVB Device Drivers](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers). As their "Basic" approach would go for more than 4 hours, I decided to deselect most options of the module:

```
git clone --depth=1 git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git
cd media_build
sudo apt-get install patchutils libproc-processtable-perl libncurses5-dev
make menuconfig # deselect most options here, keeping DVB checked
# Please ensure that the file .config contains CONFIG_DVB_CORE=m
make
sudo make install
```

## 3. Install dvbhdhomerun

Finally, you need to install [dvbhdhomerun](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvbhdhomerun/), a user-generated linux kernel module specifically for the HDHomeRun.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libhdhomerun-dev dkms dh-systemd module-assistant
git clone https://github.com/h0tw1r3/dvbhdhomerun
cd dvbhdhomerun
# Build and install the kernel module
cd kernel
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe dvb_hdhomerun
cd ..
```

This fails with:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'dvb_hdhomerun': Invalid argument
```

but never mind, it'll work nonetheless...

## 4. Install and Setup TVHeadEnd

At the time of writing this answer, there's no [apt repository](https://tvheadend.org/projects/tvheadend/wiki/AptRepository) containing ARM binaries for TVHeadEnd. You'll have to [build it from source](https://tvheadend.org/projects/tvheadend/wiki/Building).

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git pkg-config libssl-dev bzip2 wget
sudo apt-get install libavahi-client-dev zlib1g-dev libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libavresample-dev
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/tvheadend/tvheadend.git
cd tvheadend
./configure --enable-libffmpeg_static
make
sudo make install
cd ..
rm -fr tvheadend
```

You can now access TVHeadEnd in your web browser at the address: `http://<ip-of-your-raspberry-pi>:9981`.

To set up TVHeadEnd, check the Configuration tab:

1. Under DVB Inputs, select the folder above your HDHomeRun and assign a Network type.
2. Under Networks, add a network corresponding to your location
3. Back to DVB Inputs, select one of the tuners, assign the network and check the box "Enabled"
4. Under Services, you should now start to see channel names appearing
5. Under Channel / EPG > Channel, click Add and select a Services. Confirm with Apply.

You can now open the Electronic Program Guide to browse the program list and start playing/recording your TV shows.

Comment: **Small Update to 2a: the patching and compiling does not work, but here are some updates:** cd /root *#update: or any other dir in "/"* git clone https://git.linuxtv.org/cgit.cgi/media_build.git *#update URL does not work* cd media_build sudo apt-get install patchutils libproc-processtable-perl libncurses5-dev cd media_build/linux #update make download untag *#update: get media_build patches* cd .. *#update* make menuconfig #deselect most options here, keeping DVB checked Please ensure that the file .config contains `CONFIG_DVB_CORE=m` make sudo make install